# Determining function who satisfies Laplace equation.

Tags: vector-analysis, harmonic-functions

> Defining $\vec{r}=xi+yj+zk\ $ and $|\vec{r}|=r$, if $f$ is a scalar function such that $\nabla^2 f(r)=0$, then prove that $$f(r)=a+\dfrac{b}{r}$$where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

I found that $$\nabla^2 f(r)=f''(r)+\dfrac{2}{r}f'(r)=0$$

What should I do further please help?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Note that if $f$ is a function if $r$ only, then

$$\nabla^2 f(r)=\frac1{r}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}(r f(r)) \tag1$$

Set $(1)$ equal to $0$ and integrate twice.  Can you finish?

Comment: how you get that equation 1 please include in your answer.

Comment: Use the product rule to show equivalence with the expression you wrote.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.  And feel free to up vote answers and accept an answer as you see fit.